# Google places API turn predictions into Prediction

Tags: flutter, api, google-maps, google-places-api

I have this code to autocomplete addresses:

```
final request =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=$input&types=address&language=$lang&components=country:az&key=$apiKey&sessiontoken=$sessionToken';
final response = await client.get(Uri.parse(request));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final result = new Map<String, dynamic>.from(json.decode(response.body));
  if (result['status'] == 'OK') {
    // compose suggestions in a list
    GoogleMapsPlaces _places = GoogleMapsPlaces(apiKey: apiKey);
    for(Prediction p in result['predictions']){
      PlacesDetailsResponse detail = await _places.getDetailsByPlaceId(p.placeId!);
      print(detail);
    }
    return result['predictions']
        .map<Suggestion>((p) => Suggestion(p['place_id'], p['description']))
        .toList();
  }
```

However, this gives error in `for` loop line:

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Prediction'
```

I want to treat `result['predictions']` as Prediction variable so that I can get the coordinates of the address. This is how `result['predictions']` looks like

```
[{description: Yaşar Hüseynov, Baku, Azerbaijan, matched_substrings: [{length: 5, offset: 0}], place_id: EiJZYcWfYXIgSMO8c2V5bm92LCBCYWt1LCBBemVyYmFpamFuIi4qLAoUChIJWRvXZl99MEARhWIJdhJqNkgSFAoSCfkcIdZrfTBAEWts5Xpeaz80, reference: EiJZYcWfYXIgSMO8c2V5bm92LCBCYWt1LCBBemVyYmFpamFuIi4qLAoUChIJWRvXZl99MEARhWIJdhJqNkgSFAoSCfkcIdZrfTBAEWts5Xpeaz80, structured_formatting: {main_text: Yaşar Hüseynov, main_text_matched_substrings: [{length: 5, offset: 0}], secondary_text: Baku, Azerbaijan}, terms: [{offset: 0, value: Yaşar Hüseynov}, {offset: 16, value: Baku}, {offset: 22, value: Azerbaijan}], types: [route, geocode]},
```

Answer (score 0):

I used `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?place_id=$id&sensor=true&key=$apiKey` To get more information including the coordinates.